# Dynamic Curves in silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, dynamic, drawing, curve

I am writing a graphic editor kind of thing in silverlight 3 to customize tee shirts. there is a functionality to create curved lines i.e. user draws a straight line and then there is a slider to control the radius of curve and as user changes the radius the curve should be update accordingly.

I am really unable to find any link on the net that discusses how to create paths on the fly in silverlight.

any any info about this kind of work would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the sample (with code) that John recently made: [Silverlight Circle Twist](http://www.johnbruin.net/index.php/2010/01/31/silverlight-circle-twist/)
And the Win Dev Guru Petzold posted: [Text Deformation Based on Bézier Splines](http://www.charlespetzold.com/blog/2009/11/Text-Deformation-Based-on-Bezier-Splines.html) 
Both should help you a lot.